# Does Maven support multiple variants?

Tags: maven

I have a *pom* for multiple clients, the client specific code is in *com.foo.custom*. So, for customer A there are classes in *com.foo.custom.customerA*, for customer B some classes in *com.foo.custom.customerB* etc. The set of classes in *com.foo.custom.customerA* is different from those in *com.foo.custom.customerB*.

When I do *mvn package*, the code for all the customers shows up in the jar, as expected. Is there a way of selecting just one customer, e.g. *mvn package -Dcust=customerB*, and then have that one customer in the package and the others not?

Comment: You'd better extract customiseable parts to separate projects, and configure use of additional parts, which you provide or not to a particular customer, like plugin/extension or similar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can construct a multi-module project with modules like

- common
- customerA
- customerB
- ...

The customerX modules use common as dependency.

Comment: Easiest and cleanest solution also keeps calling simple `mvn package` and also works in releases...

Comment: I have implemented this, but I get one jar file when I do `mvn package`. I would have expected two, customerA.jar and customerB.jar.

Comment: When you run `mvn package` on the main POM of the project, you'll get a JAR for each module.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a pratical solution:

**pom.xml fragment**

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>ncustomerA</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.2.0</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <includes>
                            <include>src/main/java/customerA/*</include>
                        </includes>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>ncustomerB</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.2.0</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <includes>
                            <include>src/main/java/customerA
                            B/*</include>
                        </includes>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

**Build commands**

```
mvn package -P customerA
mvn package -P customerB
```

Here https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/examples/include-exclude.html further information.